# JSON Parse : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, exception

I have a variable:

```
var value=[
{"0","0",650,"0","0",357,"0","0","0","0",200,"0",48,"0",3053,"0","0","0","0","0",45,50}
,{"0","0",299,101,"0",126,"0","0","0","0",630,"0","0",88,3157,"0","0","0","0","0",10,21}
,{"0","0",123,3030,"0",368,"0","0","0","0","0","0",76,-44,1967,"0","0","0","0","0",29,64}
,{"0","0",88,343,"0",320,"0","0","0","0","0","0",175,"0",336,"0","0","0","0","0",21,98}
,{"0","0",503,410,"0",1127,"0","0","0","0","0","0",77,87,1264,"0","0","0","0","0",5,128}
,{"0","0",1754,607,40,2565,"0","0","0","0","0","0",102,70,12506,"0","0","0","0","0",178,1966}
,{"0","0","0","0",60,153,"0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0",15,"0"}
]
var result= JSON.parse(value);
```

When I parse it in JavaScript as JSON, an error occurs:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token,

Comment: There are numerous json validators you could have pasted this into before coming here. Not to mention there isn't even a question here

Comment: don't update question with the solution...it renders the original problem and answers useless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects in JSON are represented with `{}`. Object have *key-value* pairs. For example:

```
{
    "foo": "bar",
    "example: "something",
    "key": "value"
}
```

Arrays in JSON are represented with `[]`. They are a *list* of numbers, strings, objects, etc. For instance:

```
[
    "foo",
    "bar",
    "something",
    "example"
]
```

---

You're problem is that you are using `{}` for an array. Try changing your JSON to:

```
[
    ["0","0",650,"0","0",357,"0","0","0","0",200,"0",48,"0",3053,"0","0","0","0","0",45,50,["0","0",299,101,"0",126,"0","0","0","0",630,"0","0",88,3157,"0","0","0","0","0",10,21],["0","0",123,3030,"0",368,"0","0","0","0","0","0",76,-44,1967,"0","0","0","0","0",29,64],["0","0",88,343,"0",320,"0","0","0","0","0","0",175,"0",336,"0","0","0","0","0",21,98],["0","0",503,410,"0",1127,"0","0","0","0","0","0",77,87,1264,"0","0","0","0","0",5,128],["0","0",1754,607,40,2565,"0","0","0","0","0","0",102,70,12506,"0","0","0","0","0",178,1966],["0","0","0","0",60,153,"0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0",15,"0"]
]
```

Also, in JavaScript, JSON is the default Object Notation, so you don't need to call `JSON.parse` unless your JSON is being represented as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Objects in Javascript can not be presented in such way:

```
{"0","0",650,"0","0",357,"0","0","0","0",200,"0",48,"0",3053,"0","0","0","0","0",45,50}
```

An object presentation should have the following format:

```
{property_name : property_value, ... : ... , ... }
```

`JSON.parse` is expecting `':'`, but got `','`.